# Prom6 plugin and ontology files

Tags: owl, ontology

I'm working on a program with java plugin in Prom6, i'd like to know if i can import an ontology file "OWL extension" to Prom and use it as an input.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find any indication that ProM has plugins for accessing OWL ontologies. It is probably doable to write one using a Java API for this purpose (Jena or OWL API, for example), but I don't know enough about ProM to know what adapter would be required for an OWL ontology to be a meaningful input for it.

Comment: Yes i'm using Protege OWL API and i wanted to have my OWL file as an input.Thank you so much for your answer any way.

Comment: Note that protege owl api and owl api are two different libraries; the first is based on an old version of Jena and is not actively developed, as far as I know.